# Load image in tkinter from pygame surface in python 3

Tags: python, image, tkinter, pygame, geometry-surface

I would like to load an image in tkinter from a pygame surface and I am having a problem.

This is what I am currently trying:

```
image= pygame.image.tostring(surf, 'RGB')
tkimage= tkinter.PhotoImage(data= image)
canvas.create_image(0, 0, tkimage)
```

but I unfortunately get this error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize image data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`PhotoImage` class](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) can only read `GIF` and `PGM`/`PPM` files, either directly from a file or as `base64` encoded string.

---

You should use the [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) for loading and creating the image for Tk.

Here's an example:

```
import pygame
from PIL import Image
import ImageTk
import Tkinter

# load image in pygame
pygame.init()
surf = pygame.image.load('bridge.png')

# export as string / import to PIL
image_str = pygame.image.tostring(surf, 'RGB')         # use 'RGB' to export
w, h      = surf.get_rect()[2:]
image     = Image.fromstring('RGB', (w, h), image_str) # use 'RGB' to import

# create Tk window/widgets
root         = Tkinter.Tk()
tkimage      = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image) # use ImageTk.PhotoImage class instead
canvas       = Tkinter.Canvas(root)

canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=tkimage)
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

-------  UPDATE  ------

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from PIL import Image
import ImageTk
import Tkinter

# load image in pygame
pygame.init()
surf = pygame.image.load('pic_temp.png')         # you can use any Surface a Camers is also an Surface
mode = "RGB"
# export as string / import to PIL
image_str = pygame.image.tostring(surf, mode)         # use 'RGB' to export
size      = (640, 480)
#image    = Image.fromstring(mode, size, image_str) 
# use frombuffer() - fromstring() is no longer supported
image     = Image.frombuffer(mode, size, image_str, 'raw', mode, 0, 1) # use 'RGB' to import

# create Tk window/widgets
root      = Tkinter.Tk()
tkimage   = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image) # use ImageTk.PhotoImage class instead
label     = Tkinter.Label(root, image=tkimage)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation as to why this would help the user solve the issue at hand?